# Calculation in vega

Tags: vega

I use vega in Kibana.

I select two values from two different index in section "data". But now I need to summarize this values and visualize it in the section "marks". Is anybody know, how can I do this? Now in the section "marks" I use only one value from first "data".

My code is the following:

```
    {
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v3.0.json",
  "title": {
    "text": "Lead time, hr.",
    "orient": "bottom"
  },
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "source_1",
      "url": {
        "index": "metrics-bitbucket-*",
        "%context_query%": "@timestamp",
        "body": {
          "size": 0,
          "aggs": {
            "etb": {
              "avg": {
                "field": "elapsed_time",
                "script": {"source": "_value/3600*10"}
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "format": {"type": "json", "property": "aggregations.etb"}
    },
    {
      "name": "source_2",
      "url": {
        "index": "metrics-jenkins-*",
        "%context_query%": "@timestamp",
        "body": {
          "size": 0,
          "aggs": {
            "etj": {
              "avg": {
                "field": "elapsed_time",
                "script": {"source": "_value/3600*10"}
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "format": {"type": "json", "property": "aggregations.etj"}
    }
  ],
  "marks": {
    "type": "text",
    "from": {"data": "source_1"},
    "encode": {
      "update": {
        "text": {"signal": "round(datum.value)/10"},
        "fontSize": {"value": 60},
        "fontStyle": {"value": "bold"},
        "x": {"signal": "width/2-50"},
        "y": {"signal": "height/2"}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You essentially have two lists of data objects: `source1: [{}, {}, ...]` and `source2: [{}, {}, {}, ...]`.  When you draw items, you have to specify just one data source.  That data source could be the concatenation of the first two, e.g. you create `source3` with its `source` parameter set to `["source1", "source2"]`, which includes all elements from both, but I suspect this is not what you want here.  Rather, you need to merge the data using [lookup transform](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/transforms/lookup/) - iterate over the items in one data source, and pull the corresponding values from another data source. Afterwards, add a [formula transform](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/transforms/formula/) to sum the values. The mark would than use the result of the formula for drawing.